# Is installing software using serial numbers available in internet haram or halal?

Tags: halal-haram, software

Is installing software using serial numbers available in internet haram or halal?  E.g. operating systems, Photoshop and office applications.  I'm not selling things using the software, but I make websites and graphics and sell them. Even I do classes.

Comment: I cannot give an answer because but personally I do not think that it is halal. Simply consider you create your software to make money and someone finds a way to use it for free!! Would you agree?

Comment: Use Linux, LibreOffice, GIMP, Inkscape, BlueGriffon, etc., my friend, unless there's something special you cannot do with them ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It is very wrong to use softwares which others make for years in **programing, designing, planing and testing** that they charge for their living. This is the lone source of income for a programmer.

It is same as : If you make a shop for selling ice-creams and people come there and take their ice-creams for free. How you feel about that?

However, if a software is open source you can use that for free although requiring Key. You are permitted by Laws to download that on Internet.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an agreement between you (your company, your city, your country) and the manufacturer you must not use it even though there are not Muslims. [Take a look at this for more information (Persian)](http://www.pasokhgoo.ir/node/14717).

Answer (score 0):

Haram at worst possible way.It is a very tough job to create a software.Torrent make it use the software without cost.It's like using rented house without payment.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely a sin.
And you know when you commit a sin, the almighty god might forgive you but you still have to face its consequences.

The patch your using to crack a paid software might have trillion of trojans, viruses you don't know about.